# Phantom.js - Get Text Inside Alert Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, phantomjs

Is it possible to get the text inside an alert box using Phantom.js?

```
var page = require("webpage").create()
, assert = require("assert");

page.open("http://www.mysite.com/page", function (status) {
  page.includeJs("jquery-1.10.2.min.js", function () {
    var alertText = page.evaluate(function () {
      //This should cause an alert dialog to appear
      $('button[type="submit"]').click();

      //This doesn't work, but is there some equivalent to this?
      return $("alert").val();
    });

    assert.equal(alertText, "Thanks for clicking Submit!");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get the message from the `alert` that way (there is no HTML element called `<alert>`, which is what you're trying to find using jQuery). However, what you could do is redefine `window.alert` to do something else like log to the console. Then you can use `onConsoleMessage` to look at the console message. To distinguish it from other console messages that you can get, you can give it a unique prefix. I used `ALERT:` in this case:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    window.alert = function(str) {
        console.log("ALERT:" + str);
    }
});

page.onConsoleMessage(function(message, lineNumber, sourceId) {
    if(/^ALERT:/.test(message)) {
       //do something with message
    }
});
```

If you don't want to go the `onConsoleMessage` route, you could create your own hidden `input` element (in the redefined `alert`) and then simply query that value:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    window.alert = function(str) {
        if(jQuery("#alertText").length === 0) {
            jQuery("body").append(jQuery("<input>").attr("id", "alertText").attr("text", "hidden");
        }

        jQuery("#alertText").val(str);
    }
});
```

Then in your code, instead of `jQuery("alert").val()`, you would do `jQuery("#alertText").val()`.