# How to get the text inside the alert box?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some html pages, and they are `alert(some_value)`.

I want to use Javascript to get the text inside the alert box. I want something just like `document.querySeletor`, which I usually use that to get the element in the page.

But I can't find a proper api to achieve that, so could any one give me some suggestions about that?

Comment: Can you please brief a bit.document.querySeletor is use to query dom element. alert is not a dom element. You can create a variable and pass that to alert. If you need that text you can use that variable

Comment: @user2181397 How about the variable in alert is something like `alert(getUUID())`?

Comment: What is getUUID() is returning? If it is not explicitly returning any value , it will return undefined. var x = getUUID(); alert(x);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822812/phantom-js-get-text-inside-alert-box         ..Is this want you want??

Comment: @user2181397 Sorry for my implicit reply... I mean implement a user defined function which returns UUID(something like rand() in C...).

Comment: Are the `alert` calls  performed by a 3rd party code ? Then, it's bad 3rd party code, you should drop it now, but if you really want to catch the value, you can override the `window.alert` method : `(function(){
   var old = window.alert;
   window.alert = function(val){
       doSomethingWith(val);
       old(val);
       }
    })();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Are you intent to create custom alert?

Then follow this code

```js
<script>
function CustomAlert(){
    this.render = function(dialog){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Acknowledge This Message";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';
    }
 this.ok = function(){
  document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
 }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
</script>
```

```css
<style>
#dialogoverlay{
 display: none;
 opacity: .8;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background: #FFF;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox{
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 background: #000;
 border-radius:7px; 
 width:550px;
 z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox > div{ background:#FFF; margin:8px; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{ background: #666; font-size:19px; padding:10px; color:#CCC; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody{ background:#333; padding:20px; color:#FFF; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot{ background: #666; padding:10px; text-align:right; }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>My web document content ...</h1>
<h2>My web document content ...</h2>
<button onclick="alert('You look very pretty today.')">Default Alert</button>
<button onclick="Alert.render('You look very pretty today.')">Custom Alert</button>
<button onclick="Alert.render('And you also smell very nice.')">Custom Alert 2</button>
<h3>My web document content ...</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

It may be not run here but create a html page with this css and script it will work 10000%

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access alert box( I think ), but you can make your own custom alert using divs ,and you can access the contents... jquery alerts or many alert plugins are avilabe... you can get value form those